# Cannot name a function "animate" what gives?

Tags: javascript, html

So today I've ran into a weird issue, the example will explain everything:

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/23qd85b1/)

```js
function animate(arg) {
  console.log(arg);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="animate('foo')">
Run
</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MDN, the [`Element.animate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate) is a built-in experimental function:

> The `Element` interface's `animate()` method is a shortcut method which creates a new Animation, applies it to the element, then plays the animation. It returns the created Animation object instance.

In your case, it becomes `window.animate()`, which takes up a different function.

Comment: Okay thanks for explaining, but that is seriously not how it should be interpreted by the goddamn browser. I mean I understand why but.... cmon...